# Как работает RCE в изображениях?

Tags: javascript, fetch, png, jpeg, xhr

Наткнулся на историю о том, что безопасники компании где я работаю запретили использовать в качестве источника статики (изображений в том числе) внешние ресурсы.

Обусловлено опаской за Remote Code Execution.

Как вообще можно спрятать, а главное выполнить в браузере код просто загрузив .png файл?

Comment: вот у безопасников и спросите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для RCE через картинку вам "понадобится" уязвимая библиотека обработки изображений на клиенте. Чаще всего причиной уязвимости становится [переполнение буфера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), но могут быть и другие причины повреждения памяти.

Однако, такие уязвимости довольно редки, а когда их всё же находят - первыми под удар попадают рекламные сети, потом соцсети и прочие сайты где возможен пользовательский контент. Корпоративный сайт, который сослался на картинку с другого сайта тут будет последний в очереди. Так что если ваши безопасники запрещают хотлинкинг картинок с других сайтов из-за опасений RCE - они просто идиоты.

---

Однако, использовать статику с других сайтов нехорошо, и причина тут вовсе не в RCE.

Проблема в том, что владелец другого сайта может делать со своими ресурсами всё что ему вздумается, и не несёт никакой ответственности за то как после этого будет выглядеть ваш сайт. В лучшем случае эту картинку он просто удалит через какое-то время, и останется у вас на сайте вместо картинки пустое место. В худшем - он поймает вирусню, которая заменит картинку на неприличную, и эта неприличная картинка окажется на вашем сайте. А да, всё это может быть проделано только для части пользователей, то есть вы даже не можете быть уверены что все посетители вашего сайта видят ту же самую картинку что и вы сами.

Comment: Смею предположить, что запретили не потому что идиоты, а скорее картинки просто попали под раздачу, когда запрещали все статики и вместо того чтобы писать исключения сказали: Нельзя ничего) А тот кто решил задал вопрос, решил докапаться, до исключительных случаев) Т.е. хочу сказать, что вполне может быть что картинки запретили именно потому что вы описали, но не стали объяснять каждый случай отдельно)